# jQuery Remove style attributes from ALL elements

Tags: jquery, html

I know how to remove attribute from a single element, there are already some posts about that:

```
$("div.preview").removeAttr("style");
```

This is html code:

```
<div class="preview" style="background-color:white">
   <p>Some text<span style="font-size:15px;">some text</span></p>
   some more code
</div>
```

The problem is that this will remove style attribute only from preview div. I want to remove from all elements inside that div. This is just as example, in real scenario there will be more extensive html.

Is there any short way to do that?

UPDATE:
Great, I know now how to do it. But what if html is sent to function as string stored in variable. So instead of

```
$("div.preview")
```

I have

```
var string = '<div class="preview"><p style='font-size:15px;'>....</p><div>'
```

Is there any way saying something like that the below?

```
$(string).find(*).removeAttr("style");
```

Comment: Yes, select the div, select all it's children, add the div back to the collection, then remove the class.

Comment: $("div.preview, div.preview *").removeAttr("style")

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use the wildcard selector `*` to select everything underneath `div.preview`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WhZst/)

```
$('div.preview *').removeAttr('style');
```

### Update

RE: your related question, if we had a string instead of DOM elements. We could convert them into jQuery objects, remove the attribute as above and then convert them back (if desired).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2eMA/)

```
// jQuery extension to get an element's outer HTML
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/2419877/1156119
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function(s) {
    return s
        ? this.before(s).remove()
        : jQuery("<p>").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
};

var string = '<div class="preview"><p style="font-size:15px;">....</p><div>'
var elements = $(string);
elements.find('*').removeAttr('style');

var withoutStyles = elements.outerHTML();
alert(withoutStyles);
```

Comment: Tnx, I have one more question regarding this topic. Please see my update for this question.

Comment: Updated my answer with a solution.

Comment: Great. I was actually trying similar, but my mistake was I did everything in one line `$(string).find('*').removeAttr('style')`. Not sure why this is not the same.

Comment: In chrome it just remove style attribute of child element only not parent(.preview)

Answer (score 5):

try: `$("div.preview").children().removeAttr("style");`

or: `$("div.preview").find("*").removeAttr("style");` to get grandchildren too.

Comment: This will only get children, not grandchildren, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div.preview, div.preview *").removeAttr("style");
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("div.preview,div.preview *")).removeAttr("style")`

Answer (score 0):

Select the div, select it's children, then add the div back to the collection and remove class.

```
$('div.preview').find('[style]').addBack().removeAttr('style')
// replace addBack with andSelf for older jQuery
// if you don't want to remove it from the preview div, just leave addBack off.
```

however it's probably better to fix the editor rather than fix the results in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
$("div.preview").find('*').removeAttr("style");
```

To remove style from all child elements of `div.preview`

Answer (score -1):

Try doing this

```
$("#frameDemo").contents().find("#div_id").parent('div').removeAttr('onclick');
$("#frameDemo").contents().find("#div_id").children('div').removeAttr('onclick');
```